# Difference between Isomorphism and Homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I understood the formal definition of isomorphism and homomorphism.But I am not to make out difference between them.I read it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731724/what-is-the-difference-between-homomorphism-and-isomorphism), but they say that homomorphism loses information while isomorphism preserves it.Please explain what do they mean by losing information and what do they(isomorphism and homomorphism) signify.

Comment: Why do you think $f(3+7) = f(3)+f(7)$ is not true? In $\mathbb Z_2$ you have $1+1=0$.

Comment: Ok I got it my silly mistake.

Comment: Yeah that's fine, but what do they mean by losing information I don't understand.Conceptually I am not getting isomorphism and homomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When people say that a homomorphism "loses information" while an isomorphism does not, what they mean is that an isomorphism is something that you can *undo*. It depends on how you define an isomorphism, but my preferred definition is the following.

**Definition**: And isomorphism $f : A \to B$ is a (homo)morphism such that there exists a (homo)morphism $g : B \to A$ such that $f \circ g : B \to B$ and $g \circ f : A \to A$ are both the identity.

This may not be the same as your definition, but I encourage you to think about why these are actually going to be the same.

One should note that every isomorphism is in fact a homomorphism, and so these are a restricted class of homomorphisms.

The key though is that the existence of the inverse morphism $f^{-1} = g: B \to A$ allows us to "undo" what $f$ does; that is, for every $a \in A$, if we map this to $f(a) \in B$, we can recover $a$ by applying $g$.

Now, let's look by contrast at the morphism described above. The problem is that we have $f(2) = f(0) = f(100) = f(-22) = f(12345678) = 0$ etc. and so starting with the image in $B$, we can not *uniquely* recover the pre-image in $A$. So we have lost information.

Comment: Great answer, just write the meaning of f for further references.

Answer (score 1):

Isomorphism are 1 to 1 and onto and so are invertible. Every isomorphism is a Homomorphism since they have to operation preserving properties that define a Homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Losing information means the follwing :

Suppose $f(x)=f(y)=z$ , $x\ne y$.

In this case, given the value of $f(x)=z$, you cannot determine the value $x$ 
because there are different possible values. This is not the case, if
$f$ is a monomorphism. In this case, $x$ is uniquely determined by $z$.